# how to pass headers to post method of ngx-logger(serverlURL)?

Tags: angular, logging

We are currently planning to use ngx-logger in Angular 4 for server logging, but unable to pass the headers along with serverLoggingUrl.

```
 BrowserModule, HttpModule, LoggerModule.forRoot(
      { serverLoggingUrl: 'http://colwaappdev01.ros.com:20621/commonutil-exp-api/v1/log', level: 'INFO', serverLogLevel: 'INFO' })
  ],
```

can we override the _log method to pass the header parameters which is available in NGXLogger

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger/issues/23

the dev asks to utilize the interceptors to add headers. and is not updating this to add specific feature in ngx-logger package.